# New to android studio. Need advice

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I learned android development on eclipse a long time ago. Recently I have some free time. So I decided to catch up on it again.
When checking for eclipse, I saw that it is not supported now and android studio is the new way. 
My questions are...

1. Can I use the old eclipse's android SDK with android studio?
2. What are the most important changes I need to know?( basics)
3. Can android studio run on my old computer screen? With a resolution of 1024x800. Because it says on the site that it needs 1280*1024 at least.
   Thanks in advance .

Comment: SDKs haven't changed. Don't need an IDE to use them. Regarding changes... Too broad. It's a whole different IDE. Regarding your monitor, invest in a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to point Android Studio at pre installed SDK/NDK, but now they have really improved the packaging and downloading of this stuff, so I would say burn it all down and start fresh. Let Android Studio manage the SDK and it will be much easier.

Otherwise, its an IDE, pretty standard stuff. You'll have to learn gradle now to manage your project, which is the main change since Eclipse was using ant. And do get a better monitor :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you just need to change the path specified in Studio to your old Sdk that you were using with eclipse and it should work
2. Apart from different key mappings for shortcuts (you can use eclipse shortcuts in Studio too, by changing editor settings). Except that nothing special, but you got lot more ammo now. You will learn gradually about tests and different configurations in Gradle build System
3. AFAIK, that shouldnt be a problem, just that it might looked a bit crammed up

Answer (score 1):

Agree with yano, ditch the Eclipse SDKs if possible. The SDK manager is pretty hassle free on Android Studio.

Secondly, the biggest changes for me were the introduction of Gradle and a more rigid project architecture.  In Eclipse I was pretty used to putting elements all over the place in which ever folder or package I wanted.  Android Studio is a move toward convention over configuration, so projects in Android Studio tend to have similar structures.  I think this is great because it requires less configuration (and understanding of unique configurations) by me.  Also, Gradle is great.  It takes some getting used to (it seems very abstract in the beginning) but having the ability to add packages with a line of configuration beats manually adding libraries to my project.  Beyond that, I'd say AndroidManifest is at least now partially configured by your project and that Android Studios object creation wizards handle a lot more of the boiler plate code needed to create new entities.  All in all a better - more Android-centric - platform.  Took me about a month to become comfortable with the switch.  Wouldn't move back (even if that was advisable)

As for the min-resolution I'm pretty sure it will work.  I have heard of people [running below the min requirements](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2449210/minimum-screen-resolution.html).  But it will feel cramped.  All the drawers are collapsible, but I personally find Android Studio a bit more cluttered with buttons and panels than Eclipse (others may disagree).  Should work, but may not be comfortable